# localstorage reloading but not updating

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to store the results into localstorage using strictly javascript, the main goal is to pick a date, pick a time and save the results to localstorage when pressing the button so that I can later use the values, what I am finding a problem with is the fact that the local storage gets reloaded and replaced by the newest value instead of getting updated and showing a list of previous inputs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Performax Cinema</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <input type="date" id="date" required/>
        
        <select id="time" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="0">10:00 AM - 12:00 PM</option>
            <option value="1">12:00 AM - 14:00 PM</option>
            <option value="2">14:00 AM - 16:00 PM</option>
            <option value="3">16:00 AM - 18:00 PM</option>
            <option value="4">18:00 AM - 20:00 PM</option>
            <option value="5">20:00 AM - 22:00 PM</option>
        </select>`enter code here`
        <button id="btn" onclick="store()">add</button>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>


    function store()  {
    
    var time = document.querySelector("option").innerText;
    localStorage.setItem("value", JSON.stringify(time));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("value"));

    var date = document.querySelector("input").value;
    localStorage.setItem("value", date);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("value"));
}
```

Comment: you are overriding the "value" string when you called `setItem` twice in your `store()` function. Which one are you trying to store?

Comment: I am trying to store both date and time, and having the input values stored in localstorage so that I'd have a record of the different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set localStorage once. If you set item twice it will overwrite the previous one. You can set both in the local storage and then storage it in an object, then iterate through the object however you like.

```
function store()  {
    
    var time = document.querySelector("option").innerText;
    var date = document.querySelector("input").value;

    localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(time), date);
    console.log(localStorage);

    //store in object
    const items = { ...localStorage};
    console.log(Object.entries(items))
}
```

Comment: what I was curious about is whether there is a possibility to store sessions? like to just show an overall history of what was pressed? Meaning I'd press the button for a certain number of times, 5 tops, and then it would show me the different dates i picked those 5 times. Thank you so much btw.

Comment: I was wondering if incrementing localstorage would work or the .getItem() however I am not sure how to implement that

Comment: Yes you can store sessions. You can use window.sessionStorage to store the data. For you case I put the buttons inside a form and have a submit button, so you can just get the values after the form is submitted and store it in the session. You can add a handler or function to the form that will make it so you can submit 5 times like you want. I hope this helps

Comment: And is there a way for you to share the code?

Comment: That would be very highly appreciated and I appreciate the help